# Multi-Nested Elastic Query

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to return all documents that match a specific keyword property in a collection.

The image below represents the document hierarchy.

The **AggregateRoot** has a collection of GUID Id's in the property **DomainElements**.

I am trying write a query that returns all documents where the Id matches a specific Guid value.

[image]

the following image shows the nested path in the index schema;

[image]

When I attempt this query I do not return any results...

```
{
"query": {
    "nested": {
        "path": "boundedContexts",
        "query": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "boundedContexts.aggregateRoots",
                  "query": {
                    "nested": {
                    "path": "boundedContexts.aggregateRoots.domainElements",
                        "query": {
                            "bool": {
                                "must": [
                                    { "match": { "domainelements.id": "48be3bb4-838d-44a5-85e3-c5ea4fa8ee36" } }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Here is the index documents which shows the data I am trying to query does exist ...

[image]

What am I missing?

Is there a more simplified way to query these results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it -- just make sure the complete nested path is included in the field name you're targeting:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "boundedContexts",
      "query": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "boundedContexts.aggregateRoots",
          "query": {
            "nested": {
              "path": "boundedContexts.aggregateRoots.domainElements",
              "query": {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "match": {
                        "boundedContexts.aggregateRoots.domainElements.id": "48be3bb4-838d-44a5-85e3-c5ea4fa8ee36"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

BTW there's no need for so many (sub)nested queries. The inner-most nested path is enough:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "boundedContexts.aggregateRoots.domainElements",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "boundedContexts.aggregateRoots.domainElements.id": "48be3bb4-838d-44a5-85e3-c5ea4fa8ee36"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @JoeSorocin, that works great! I was not aware that I need only include the inner most nested path. This type of query is required within my code-generated Projections thus it will be super easy to determine the inner-most nested path and match field list without needing to walk the entire hierarchical graph.

Comment: Nice -- I'm glad your code got simplified! Hey btw I'm writing an elasticsearch handbook full of solutions to non-trivial, real-word use cases and there's a chapter or two on nested fields! If you [let me know in my short survey](https://jozefsorocin.typeform.com/to/XeQRxdwV) what else you'd like to learn about, I'll let you know when the handbook is out.

Comment: Fantastic Joe, I completed you short survey and look forward to your book.

Comment: Awesome, John   Appreciate it.